# ConcurrentModificationException in synchronized collection

Tags: java

I am using `SynchronizedCollection.containsAll` problem is facing is when i ever i run the following code i am getting `ConcurrentModification Exception`.

From my understanding code should terminate without any exception.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l1 = new LinkedList(), l2 = new LinkedList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            l1.add("" + i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            l2.add("" + i);
        }
        // reverse to make the search take a little longer
        Collections.reverse(l2);
        final List sl1 = Collections.synchronizedList(l1);
        final List sl2 = Collections.synchronizedList(l2);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // synchronized (sl2) {
                sl1.containsAll(sl2);
                // }
            }
        }.start();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                sl2.add("3");
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Can some one help me understand why i am getting this exception.

Comment: Have you read `Collections.synchronizedList()`'s javadoc ?

Comment: Why do you think sl1 is in synchronized with sl2?

Comment: instead of `Thread.sleep(100);` change it to `Thread.sleep(1000);` and you will see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation of `Collections::synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-)

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it.

In your example, when you run `sl.containsAll(sl2)`, you iterate over `sl2` without synchronizing on `sl2`. That's admittedly an implementation detail of the `containsAll` method but [it is clearly indicated in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-):

> This implementation iterates over the specified collection, checking each element returned by the iterator in turn to see if it's contained in this collection.

You can fix the problem by synchronizing on `sl2` (i.e. uncomment the code that you have commented out).

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code, i think exception is intended but if current code

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
synchronized(mutex) {return c.containsAll(coll);}
        }
```

is changed to....

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> coll) {
synchronized(mutex) {
               synchronized(coll) {
              return c.containsAll(coll);}}
        }
```

Then the problem will be fixed.

Comment: That could easily lead to deadlocks and there is no reason to assume that `coll` is a synchronized collection.